# Laravel nova belongsTo filter

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-nova

I have one table championships and one table users. Also I have same models (championship and user).

In one championship may be one main judge, main secretary and judge operator. All of them also are roles in my application and stored in roles table.

I have created new a resource Championship with 3 belongsTo fields. All of them searchable.

```
        BelongsTo::make('Main judge', 'mainJudge', User::class)
            ->onFormsAndDetail()
            ->searchable(),

        BelongsTo::make('Main secreatary', 'mainSecretary', User::class)
            ->onFormsAndDetail()
            ->searchable(),


        BelongsTo::make('Judge operator', 'judgeOperator', User::class)
            ->onFormsAndDetail()
            ->searchable(),
```

During the search I need filter query in order to search give only users with same roles.

For example, during the search main judge I have to include next filter into query

```
select *
from users u
join users_roles ur on u.id = ur.user_id
join roles r on ur.role_id = r.id
where r.alias = 'judge'
```

I have found some methods into app/Nova/Resource.php such as *relatableQuery* but how can I use it inside User resource if I have 3 fields with User.

Answer (score 3):

on Championship resource you have to create function with name of relation.

e.g.

```
public static function relatableMainSecretary(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{
    return $query->where(...);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that relatable method I have to create on championship resource? Because associatableQueryMethod search relatable method on User model

Answer (score 3):

Nova now has this as of 4.19.0 in the form of `relatableQueryUsing()`, which takes a closure parameter that allows you to modify the query building on the way through. This means you don't need to inspect the request slug when you relate the same model multiple times since it's doable on a per-field basis.

Docs: https://nova.laravel.com/docs/4.0/resources/relationships.html#relatable-query-filtering

In your specific case, would look something like this:

```
BelongsTo::make('Main judge', 'mainJudge', User::class)
    // THIS IS NEW
    ->relatableQueryUsing(function (NovaRequest $request, Builder $query) {
        // BUILD YOUR CONDITIONS HERE
        $query->where(...);
    })
    ->onFormsAndDetail()
    ->searchable(),
```

Based on the original SQL provided, you may also need to use some joins to get to the condition you want.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest (and unofficial) way to achieve this is to sniff how request URL is structured. With that in mind you can simply override `relatableQuery` method in your `Nova/User` class.

That's how it can be done, please keep in mind that `strtolower` function is optional and just saves unnecessary hassle with case sensitive typos.

```php
public static function relatableQuery(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{
    $requestSegment = strtolower($request->segment(4));

    if ($requestSegment === 'mainjudge') {
        return $query->where(...);
    }

    if ($requestSegment === 'mainsecretary') {
        return $query->where(...);
    }

    if ($requestSegment === 'judgeoperator') {
        return $query->where(...);
    }
    
    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify query using https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/authorization.html#dynamic-relatable-methods

`User.php` resource

```
public static function relatableUser(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{
    if ($request->segment(4) === 'mainjudge' && $request->search) {
        return $query->where(); // your query
    }

    return  $query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is if you want to use the current instance id

```
public static function relatableQuestionOptions(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{
    $resource = $request->newResourceWith($request->findModelQuery())->first();
    if(!$resource) {
        return;
    }
    return $query->where('exam_question_id', $resource->id);
}
```